# SVG filter works in chrome but not in Safari or FireFox

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a inline SVG with a filter that creates a shadow. It works in the latest version of Chrome but not in FireFox or Safari. I'm I missing something?

Here is the HTML:

```
<svg class="blue shape-triangle-3 shape-triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="415" height="455" viewBox="0 0 415 455" data-reactid="48">
  <defs data-reactid="49">
    <filter id="shape-triangle" width="182.4%" height="172.4%" x="-41.2%" y="-27.2%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" data-reactid="50">
      <feOffset dy="30" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" data-reactid="51"></feOffset>
      <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="35" data-reactid="52"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.3 0" data-reactid="53"></feColorMatrix>
      <feMerge data-reactid="54">
        <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1" data-reactid="55"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" data-reactid="56"></feMergeNode></feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
<g filter="url(#shape-triangle)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-106 -734)" data-reactid="57">
  <path class="shape-" d="M170.912 767.496l287.176 74.364a2 2 0 0 1 1.204 2.98l-154.94 253.066a2 2 0 0 1-3.56-.295L168.556 770.18a2 2 0 0 1 2.356-2.685z" data-reactid="58"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And this is the CSS that is used for the fill:

```
.shape-triangle path {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Also made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgZaVQ)

Comment: feMergeNode takes a shadowMatrixOuter1 but there's no such thing. Your filter pipeline is broken.

Comment: Add type="matrix" and result="shadowMatrixOuter1" to your feColorMatrix filter This is a basic syntax error so voted to close.